# discord.js disable “interaction failed”

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

If an interaction (for example button click) is not replied, discord will display “interaction failed” in the client

What they expect you to do: `inter.reply(‘stuff’)`

What I want to do: `inter.channel.send(‘stuff’)`

This is not an error I just want to prevent “interaction failed” from showing up, is there anyway to do that?

Comment: So do you want to change `"interaction failed"` to something else or make it not showing up at all?

Comment: What I mean by is this https://i.imgur.com/2l6QWZm_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`ButtonInteraction.deferUpdate()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=deferUpdate). This will not show "This interaction failed", it replies with saying that you will edit it later<sup>[1]</sup>, though it won't show any content like the `Bot is thinking...`

```js
inter.deferUpdate();
inter.channel.send("some content")
```

<sup>[1]: You don't **have** to update it after</sup>

Comment: Note: this only exists on `MessageComponentInteraction`s (Buttons and Select Menus)