# How to end interaction silently?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I have a 'say' command, that doesn't reply back to the user, but just "says" whatever the user types. But it seems like my bot expects to reply back to the user, which I think is unnecessary in this case. Is there a way to just end the interaction without the bot timing out and saying an error occurred? I know deferReply exists, but that just makes the bot display the "Bot is thinking..." message. I just don't want any reply to be sent. Here is the relevant code:

```
  async execute(interaction) {
    await interaction.channel.send(interaction.options.getString("string"));
  }
```

EDIT:
I believe the closest way to do this would be to send a message, then delete it immediatly after:

```
  async execute(interaction) {
    await interaction.reply({
      content: `.`,
    });
    await interaction.deleteReply();
    await interaction.channel.send(interaction.options.getString("string"));
  },
```

Discord really should add the ability to just silently end interactions like:

```
await interaction.noReply();
```

Comment: This only exists for `MessageComponentInteraction`s - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902967/discord-js-disable-interaction-failed

Comment: @MrMythical so I would have to implement some sort of system where I send a message and instantly delete it?

Comment: interaction.noReply() is definitely a must, but fortunately deferUpdate() works for my case

Answer (score 4):

There is no real solution to not reply to a slash command.
Below will only work for select menus and buttons.
`<Interaction>.deferUpdate()` acknowledges the interaction without doing anything else.
No errors or replies will be required after an interaction is acknowledged.

Comment: I believe this is only for bot messages that contain buttons. I don't think this works with just regular messages, based on my own testing.

Comment: Correct, I forgot to include the information